# regex match as 1 unit

Tags: php, regex

I am using the PHP to run a regex on some strings.

The strings looks like:

```
somethingsomethin.somethingsomething.extension
```

I want to match the bits between the 2 periods and including the 2 periods part in the above:

```
.somethingsomething.
```

I came up with something simple like: `\..+\.`

The problem is that it matches all the periods in something like this:

`somethingsomethin....somethingsomething....extension` matches as `....somethingsomething....` when I only want `.somethingsomething.`.

How can I get my regex expression to match as "1 unit" and to match only once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `.` matches a `.`, exclude literal `.`s: `\.[^.]+\.` or possibly `\.\w+\.`.

Comment: Great idea! Never thought about doing it this way :)

Answer (score 0):

The `.` matches entire string oin your example. Try this:

```
<?php

$str = 'somethingsomethin....somethingsomething....extension';

preg_match('#\.\w+\.#', $str, $m);

print_r($m);
```